# how to combine the rows of a multi row sub query with a conditional statement to be used in In in T-sql

Tags: t-sql, in-subquery

I'm trying to get the records of the Parent Department if exists from the view `PayrollView`as well the child departments provided `DepartmentSecurityMode=2`. The rows are filtered on parent Department Id. This is what I tried but it shows me the error

**"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."**

```
DECLARE @LoggedInUserId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                         = 'ff333441-bc4f-4f3d-b992-aad17baa9ebc'
DECLARE @LoggedInRoleId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                         = '2cb31771-7cbc-4f38-b558-804308d908c7'
DECLARE @DepartmentId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                       = '989fd98a-33ae-4ce1-8bbd-ed51ac46137d'
DECLARE @PeriodId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'e7e52d21-90ad-4f2d-adc2-3f5399a032dd'

SELECT *
FROM PayrollView pv
INNER JOIN Departments d
ON pv.DepartmentId = d.SysId
CROSS JOIN AppRoles r
LEFT JOIN UserDepartmentView rd
ON d.SysId = rd.DepartmentId
AND rd.RoleId = @LoggedInRoleId
AND rd.UserId = @LoggedInUserId
WHERE PeriodId = @PeriodId
AND r.SysId = @LoggedInRoleId
AND 
(
    r.DepartmentSecurityMode = 2
    AND D.SysId IN
    ( 
        (
            SELECT SysId
            FROM Departments ds
            WHERE ds.ParentHierarchy LIKE
             '%' + cast (@DepartmentId AS VARCHAR (50)) + '%'
        )
        ,
        --This is where I want to combine both the child as well the parent.
        (
            CASE
                WHEN @DepartmentId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN D.SysId
                ELSE @DepartmentId
            END
        )
    )
)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: t-sql does not have a != operator, are you sure about your tag?

Comment: How does `D.SysId` relate to the `case when @DepartmentId` code in the subquery?  I couldn't follow the logic of what you wanted to return.

Comment: @JohnLBevan when I pass the ``@DepartmentId`` then filter the result set based on the passed ``DepartmentId``and as well select the child departments, else get all the departments from the query result.``D.SysId`` in (SysId that the sub query returns, case when ``@DepartmentId= empty then D.SysId else @DepartmentId``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your requirement, but as [@Johey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206674/361842) points out in his answer, there is an issue with your `IN` statement.
Try replacing logic for `D.SysId in` with this code / let us know if this does what you'd hoped...

```
AND D.SysId IN
( 
    SELECT SysId
    FROM Departments ds
    WHERE ds.ParentHierarchy LIKE '%' + cast (@DepartmentId AS VARCHAR (50)) + '%'

    UNION

    SELECT CASE
        WHEN @DepartmentId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN D.SysId
        ELSE @DepartmentId
    END
)
```

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I was trying for. It's working perfectly. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying something weird there: with the condition `<expression> IN (...)` you can filter records that exist in a list of items. That list can be values separated by commas OR a subquery. You are combining both which is (according to my knowledge) not possible.

So you have to separate these two techniques...

**Update:**

@JohnLBevan 's answer is an option, but I think you could simplify the logic by doing this:

```
AND (
      -- don't filter if no department provided 
      @DepartmentId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

      OR 

      -- filter on the given department
      D.SysId IN ( 
                    SELECT SysId
                    FROM Departments ds
                    WHERE ds.ParentHierarchy LIKE '%' + cast (@DepartmentId AS 
VARCHAR (50)) + '%'
                  )
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are suggesting me?